# loop list of words with Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a function which take a dictionary af words and a sentence (sent).
The problem is that in this loop :

```
  for word in s:
```

It doesn't take words per words (words coposinf the sentence), but character per character.

I don't know why.

Any idea please?

Thanks

```
def compute_tfidf(word_counter, sent):
    word_counter = {}
    total_count = 0
    no_of_sentences = 0    
    sents_emd = []
    print(sent)

    for s in sent :
        total_count = total_count + len(s)

        no_of_sentences = no_of_sentences +  1



        for word in s:
            print(word)
            print(word_counter[word])

    return sents_emd
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `for word in string.split(' ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `s` is a string you will loop it character by character. If you want to loop each word in a sentence string, try `for word in s.split()` which will split a string on spaces into a list by default.

if  `total_count` is supposed to count words you probably also want to use `len(s.split())`.. at that point you might want to just use a variable like `sentence = s.split()` at the start of the loop.